# How to pass value from JInternalFrame to JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, jinternalframe

i just want to know how to pass a value like string from `JInternalFrame` to `JDialog`. `JDialog` is a child form and `JInternalFrame` is a parent form. If you can please show me a simple example.

here is my code , i want to pass id from ProductDetails to AddQuantity , i tried to use static but it's not working

```
public class ProductDetails extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame {
String id;
    public ProductDetails() throws Exception {
        initComponents();
}
//This is a button to go to JDialog
 private void btnAddQuantityActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        id = txtID.getText();
        AddQuantity aq = new AddQuantity(null, true);
        aq.setLocationRelativeTo(aq);
        aq.setVisible(true);
}
}


public class AddQuantity extends javax.swing.JDialog {
    ProductDetails pd;
    public AddQuantity(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        //i use showMessage to show result but it show me nothing 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, pd.id);
        txtCurrentID.setText(pd.id);
    }
    }
```

Comment: You should show some code for better results and explain what you want passed and if the state should be shared and updated. The context is not clear enough to get _correct_ answer.

Comment: In the constructor of the class that uses a JDialog?  Isn't that what class constructors are for?

Answer (score 0):

Well according to me There is no specific Method to do this but u can do one thing that Declare Data static and u can access that static Thing into The Dialog Box too. So u can show it There :)

Other thing is Make method With input parameters Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

- Pass your `JFrame` as owner of `JDialog`.
- Call  `JDialog#getOwner()` to get the owner
- Get the desired value from owner

Comment: sorry i have mistake , it's JInteralFrame not JFrame . i have tried pass JInternalFrame as owner of JDialog by super() method but there is no any option return JInternalFrame just have return Frame

Comment: cast it to `JInternalFrame`.